# Initializer in a Swift Class

Tags: swift, class, constructor, initializer

I have come to Swift from other languages. There is a pattern I sometimes use in defining a class in which the initializer calls another function which would be called later to re-initialize.

```swift
class Test {
    var thing: String
    init() {
        reinit()    //  'self' used in method call 'load' before all stored properties are initialized
    }               //  Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
    func renit() {
        self.thing = "Hello"
    }
}
```

In this case, it doesn’t work. I really don’t want to write the initializing code twice, and I can’t use `test.init()`, apparently to re-intialize.

What is the correct way of doing this?

**Update**

A few comments suggest that this is a bad design, and it may well be. In reality, of course, the application will not be so trivial.

The point is that I can do it this way in other languages, so I’m wondering what is the correct approach in Swift.

Comment: Reinitializing objects is kind of strange, and *really* error prone. What exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this? If the overhead of object allocation/deallocation is a concern, I would instead use a struct. If you need reference semantics, and still need object reuse, I would model that as a struct within a class. Reinitializing an object is involves creating a new struct instance, which runs its regular initializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object can be "re-initialized" then just initialize it to some base-state by default:

```
class Test {
    var thing: String = "" // Add default value
    init() {
        reinit()
    }          

    func reinit() {
        self.thing = "Hello"
    }
}
```

As a rule, I think this is probably a bad design. Instead of "reinitializing," replace this class with a struct, and just throw it away and replace it when you want to reset things. As a rule, structs are very cheap to create. But if you need this, then default values is ok.

Comment: I think this approach is probably the simplest. I just thought it odd that you can’t call another method without first initialising the variables.

Comment: @Manngo Intentionally so. While it has some negative repercussions, it means your methods *never* have to concern themselves with defending against being called on uninitialized objects.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to make `thing` into an implicitly unwrapped optional. This sound dangerous, but it's really just a regression to what almost every other language does (e.g. Java, Ruby, Python, JS, where all object references behave like IUOs).

Alternatively, you duplicate the assignments. If the values are complex, you can extract, like so:

```
class Test {
    var thing: String
    init() {
        self.thing = generateThing()
    }

    func renit() {
        self.thing = generateThing()
    }

    func generateThing() -> String { "Hello" }
}
```